# Add attribute to HTML element if $scope.myVar exists

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a `disabled` attribute to an input if `$scope.myVar` is null, and remove it when `$scope.myVar` is not null. What is the best way to do this?

**Example input:**

```
<input name="foo" ng-model="bar" />
```

I know we can do `ng-if` on the entire element, but I couldn't find any syntax for particular attributes.

**My overly verbose solution:**

```
<input name="foo" ng-model="bar" disabled ng-if="!myVar" />
<input name="foo" ng-model="bar" ng-if="myVar" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ng-disabled` directive

```
<input name="foo" ng-model="bar" ng-disabled="myVar == null" />
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation inside the disabled attribute.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll accept when the timer is up.  Is there a general way to do this for other attributes?

Comment: @DonnyP every attribute working like disabled (readonly for example) has a corresponding ng directive. Read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of the [`ng-disabled` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<input name="foo" ng-model="bar" ng-disabled="!myVar" />
```